# Python multiprocessing queue get and put

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I am trying to use python multiprocessing to fill a queue with strings and then print them back out but am having trouble. Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
import multiprocessing

my_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
my_list  =[i for i in range(0,100)]

def enqueue(q):
    for data in my_list:
        q.put(data)

def get_it(q):
    while not q.empty():
        item = q.get()
        print(item)


p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=enqueue, args=(my_q,))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_it, args=(my_q,))
p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()
```

This program executes without printing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `get_it` is executed before the queue is populated, it will return immediately, printing nothing.

You need to make sure the queue is populated before the `get_it` is called.

For example, wait until `enqueue` is called until all items are enqueued:

```
...

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=enqueue, args=(my_q,))
p1.start()
p1.join()

p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_it, args=(my_q,))
p2.start()
p2.join()
```

Or modifying `get_it` like below not to end too early:

```
...

def get_it(q):
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        if item is None:  # loop until sentinel value (None) appear.
            break
        print(item)


my_list.append(None)  # sentinel value to denote end of input value
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=enqueue, args=(my_q,))
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_it, args=(my_q,))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

or use `multiprocess.pool.Pool.map` instead:

```
import multiprocessing.pool

def get_it(item):
    print(item)

pool = multiprocessing.pool.Pool()
pool.map(get_it, range(100))
```